# How do you merge multiple rows into a single row in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, separate by comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to concatenate the below IDs into one single row based on the matching user_id.

Current Code

```
SELECT
A.USER_ID,
B.POINT_ID

FROM DATABASE1 AS A
LEFT JOIN DATABASE2 as b on a.SSCL_ID = b.SEC_ID

WHERE
RECORD_STATUS in ('2','5')
and USER_STATUS = '1'
```

I tried the below code:

```
SELECT c.USER_ID,
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + cast(POINT_ID as varchar(10))
            FROM DATABASE1 A
            LEFT JOIN DATABASE2 as b on a.SSCL_ID = b.SEC_ID
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
    from DATABASE1 c
      WHERE
       RECORD_STATUS in ('2','5')
       and USER_STATUS = '1'
    group by c.USER_ID
```

Comment: You're missing your implicit JOIN in the subquery with a `WHERE`

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment. I have LEFT JOIN DATABASE2 as b on a.SSCL_ID = b.SEC_ID. Does something need to be added?

Comment: So what relationship does `c` have with `a` and `b`? It's a cross join in your query. `c` is related to *every* row in your subquery (consisting of the data from `a` and `b`).

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner `FOR XML PATH` aggregation must be a function of the outer `USER_ID`

```
with cte as(
    SELECT
      A.USER_ID,
      B.POINT_ID
    FROM DATABASE1 AS A
    LEFT JOIN DATABASE2 as b on a.SSCL_ID = b.SEC_ID
    WHERE
      RECORD_STATUS in ('2','5')
      and USER_STATUS = '1'
)
SELECT c1.USER_ID,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast(POINT_ID as varchar(10))
            FROM cte c2
            WHERE c2.USER_ID = c1.USER_ID
            FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM cte c1
```

Comment: `FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')` to prevent XML entitization

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [USER_ID] VARCHAR(10), POINT_ID INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl ([USER_ID], POINT_ID) VALUES
('T0070',1 ),
('T0070',2 ),
('T0070',3 ),
('T1234',10),
('T1234',11),
('T1234',12),
('T1234',13),
('T1234',14);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT p.[USER_ID], 
   STUFF((SELECT @separator + CAST(POINT_ID AS VARCHAR(30)) AS [text()]
      FROM @tbl AS c
      WHERE c.[USER_ID] = p.[USER_ID] 
      ORDER BY c.POINT_ID
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, NULL) AS POINT_ID_LIST
FROM @tbl AS p
GROUP BY p.USER_ID;
```

**Output**

```
+---------+----------------+
| USER_ID | POINT_ID_LIST  |
+---------+----------------+
| T0070   |          1,2,3 |
| T1234   | 10,11,12,13,14 |
+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks, took it into account. The OP is quiet for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `string_agg()`?

```
SELECT A.USER_ID, STRING_AGG(B.POINT_ID, ',')
FROM DATABASE1 A LEFT JOIN
     DATABASE2 b 
     ON a.SSCL_ID = b.SEC_ID
WHERE RECORD_STATUS in ('2', '5') AND
      USER_STATUS = '1'
GROUP BY A.USER_ID;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon. Just tried that and it gave me error "'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: @Meowzz You need SQL Server 2017+